# Add element to array in the conditional statement of a loop in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I have this piece of code:

```
while ($i = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
    $items[] = $i;
}
```

I tried neatening it to this:

```
while ($items[] = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC));
```

It looks very satisfying but I now get an extra element at the end of the array (when the call to `fetchArray()` returns false. Is there a way of writing this statement without getting the extra element at the end?

Comment: are you using PDO? if yes, there's a nice fetchAll method that's perfect for you

Comment: @STTLCU why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: I believe he's using `mysqli`, it should have a [fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) all the same.

Comment: @dbf: mysqli works with sqlite? I didn't think about that, honestly.

Comment: @STTLCU so true ;) .. I didn't see the `SQLITE3_ASSOC` argument in `fetchArray`, only read `fetchArray` and automatically ready `mysqli` instead :D. He's using PHP's [SQLITE3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) class set. Whereas SQLITE's results statement does not have a `fetchAll` kind of method :|

Comment: @dbf thanks, i've addressed this situation in my latest edit.

Comment: Yes, I am using the sqlite3 library, so no fetchall :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
while(($item=$res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))&&$items[]=$item);
```

Comment: How is that better than the original?

Comment: Some more detailed info on why this is better would indeed be very useful instead of _Try this_, etc. ;)

Comment: If $item is null, it won't add it to $items. It's what OP was asking for. (Short-circuit evaluation.)

Comment: hammurabi: @dbf isn't saying that your answer is wrong, just that to make your answer more useful to novice programmers it would be better if you'd explain WHY does this work.

Comment: @hammurabi Though this answer is what the OP is asking for, it lacks information and your comment on supplying information is not helping.  The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) says _Returns a result row as an associatively or numerically indexed array or both. Alternately will return FALSE if there are no more rows._. `null` will never be returned but `false` instead. In the `if` statement, `$item` requires to be any other value but `false` in order to add any value in `$items`. And you are still missing a dollar sign `$` as in `&& $items[]=$item`

Comment: And do note that `$item = array(); if($item)` equals `if(false)`, and equivalent.

Comment: I think this is as close as can be done to my ideal statement. Thank you. It sadly lacks readability and sex appeal.

Comment: @TonyH don't you just hate it when it has everything you think it has but eventually missing sex appeal .. It's like eating an apple but you keep telling yourself it's an orange, gosh! :D

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PDO as your database library, you should use the `fetchAll()` method ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php))

```
$items = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

This will provide you a bidimensional associative array. Its index goes from 0 to n-1 where n is the fetched rows count and every row contains an array with column names as indexes. For example:

```
$items[3]['id']
```

will contain the value stored in the id column of the 4th fetched row.

if you're using mysqli_* instead, there is [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) but it's discouraged because it's more expensive rather a loop of mysqli_fetch_array(), or so the documentation says.

If you're using a third party library, consult the provided documentation. If there is none provided or there is no `fetchAll` equivalent it's a sign of poor quality. Drop it and use the native PDO instead.

Since you're using SQLITE3 driver, i suggest you to look at this page: [SQLITE (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) which explains how to use PDO with SQLITE3. Believe me, it's worth it. Most probably you won't stick to SQLITE for long and when you'll migrate to MySQL or PostgreSQL you'll thank me for this read.

PDO's main advantage is that's (usually) transparent to the user regarding which DB is below. Therefore, it shouldn't break your application if you change database, just change the PDO connection string and it'll be enough.